# Detect if client is downloading using socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Can I use socket for detecting if the client is downloading?
I want also to get some information about the file downloading.
Some information are the ff:
File Name
File Size
File Type

I tried researching on JNETPCAP but they used packet and I don't understand about the packets.

Comment: We can't possibly answer this question without more information.  Are you the client?  If so, you know you're downloading because... _you_ are downloading the file.  Are you the server?  If so, you know the client is downloading because _you_ are sending the file.  Are you someone else?  If so... what socket?  I see no socket here.

Comment: I will create a java application to be installed in computer of the supervisor. It must have a feature that other computers connected to the network will be detected if they are downloading files.

Comment: That should all be part of your question --- it drastically changes the kind of answer you're looking for (and who can answer it).  Your question might still be too broad for Stack Overflow, so provide whatever extra detail you can, including whatever you failed to understand about network packets (which you will _have_ to deal with for this project).  Alternatively... this sounds like the sort of product you could just _buy_ somewhere, so look for commercial software that already does what you need, or free-software equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't detect if the client is downloading something, unless maybe you could intercept the network traffic (you might need promiscuous mode). That'd be really difficult to do though.